# Heroku add:keys error

Tags: heroku

i have a git / rails project working i can commit and my ssh key is working soo i did the

sudo gem install heroku and :

Successfully installed heroku-1.14.4

1 gem installed

Installing ri documentation for heroku-1.14.4...

Installing RDoc documentation for heroku-1.14.4...

well and then i got this error :

joe@St1gm4:~/apps/project$ heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Uploading ssh public key /home/joe/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Enter your Heroku credentials.

Email: joe@gmail.com

Password:

**Resource not found**

anyone have a solution that can help me ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The "Resource not found" error will happen when the credentials are not correct. The password is the one used when creating a heroku account.